# setOnEndOfMedia change scene

Tags: javafx, media-player, actionevent

I have a `MediaPlayer` and I want to change the scene on the end of media
i tried to use `setOnEndOfMedia` but it takes runnable as argument and couldn't cast `ActionEvent` to `Runnable`

Comment: Show the code that is giving the error.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply define a runnable event:

```
mp.setOnEndOfMedia(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // actions here e.g.:
        primaryStage.hide();
    }
});
```